# How to write a unit test for an Ansible filter function

Tags: python, unit-testing, ansible

I have written an Ansible role with a filter function class, located in `my_role/filter_plugins/MyFilterClass.py`. I'd like to write a unit test for the Python class (just testing the Python code, *not* testing the whole role with Molecule). I'm struggling with the test setup. I found the following solution, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is considered to be best practice:

I have placed my unit test in `my_role/test/MyFilterClassTest.py`. I've added the following code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730946/130121)) to the top of the file to be able to import my class:

```py
import os
import sys
import pathlib
import unittest

PACKAGE_PARENT = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent
SCRIPT_DIR = PACKAGE_PARENT / "filter_plugin"
sys.path.append(str(SCRIPT_DIR))

from MyFilterClass import FilterModule

# Unit test goes here ...
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe using a different folder structure/naming convention and `ansible-test`?